# Pass Data between ManagedBeans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have one Class called Foo. And one ManagedBean called FooBean. In a page (Facelet) I get a new Foo info from user and insert it to DB. After first submission of data the print button will be enabled. Now I need the user click the print button and see the other page (Facelet) which is the print page with PrintFooBean. How can I pass the ID of the recently inserted Foo to the PrintFooBean and load it and display its items on the printing page?

What is the best way?
And I prefer the user to see the print page in a new browser window/tab.

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html

Comment: @org: this article is still targeted on JSF 1.2. In JSF 2.0 there are so many better/nicer ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as request parameter.

```
<a href="print.jsf?id=#{foo.id}" target="_blank">print</a>
```

or unobtrusively progressively enhanced by JS `window.open`

```
<a href="print.jsf?id=#{foo.id}" target="_blank"
    onclick="window.open('print.jsf?id=#{foo.id}'); return false;">print</a>
```

Populate the print bean with the `id`.

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
private Long id;
```

Preload the `Foo` data in same bean based on `id`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.foo = fooDAO.find(id);
}
```

Comment: That's what I've done so far, but is there any JSF standard solution instead of target="_blank" or JS?

Comment: Not in standard JSF implementation. For candyness you need to head to a 3rd party rich UI JSF component library. For example [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) which has a [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) for this purpose or even [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf) with instant row selection.